# Missing something when decompressing HTTP gzipped response

Tags: c++, qt, http, gzip

I have recently been setting up various testing environments and in this cas I nneed to read and decode a gzip response from a HTTP server. I know what I have so far works as I have tested it with wireshark and hardcoded data as outlined below, my question is what is wrong with how I am handling the gizzped data from a HTTP server?

Here is what Im using:

From this thread http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30031-qUncompress-data-from-gzip I am using the gzipDecopress function with the data provided and seeing that it works.

```
QByteArray gzipDecompress( QByteArray compressData )
{

//Hardcode sample data
const char dat[40] = {
            0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xAA, 0x2E, 0x2E, 0x49, 0x2C, 0x29,
            0x2D, 0xB6, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0xCC, 0x29, 0x4E, 0xAD, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x03, 0x00,
            0x2A, 0x63, 0x18, 0xC5, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
compressData = QByteArray::fromRawData( dat, 40);

//decompress GZIP data

   //strip header and trailer
     compressData.remove(0, 10);
     compressData.chop(12);

     const int buffersize = 16384;
     quint8 buffer[buffersize];

     z_stream cmpr_stream;
     cmpr_stream.next_in = (unsigned char *)compressData.data();
     cmpr_stream.avail_in = compressData.size();
     cmpr_stream.total_in = 0;

     cmpr_stream.next_out = buffer;
     cmpr_stream.avail_out = buffersize;
     cmpr_stream.total_out = 0;

     cmpr_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
     cmpr_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;

     if( inflateInit2(&cmpr_stream, -8 ) != Z_OK) {
             qDebug() << "cmpr_stream error!";
     }

       QByteArray uncompressed;
       do {
               int status = inflate( &cmpr_stream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH );

               if(status == Z_OK || status == Z_STREAM_END) {
                       uncompressed.append(QByteArray::fromRawData((char *)buffer, buffersize - cmpr_stream.avail_out));
                       cmpr_stream.next_out = buffer;
                       cmpr_stream.avail_out = buffersize;
               } else {
                        inflateEnd(&cmpr_stream);
                       }

               if(status == Z_STREAM_END) {
                   inflateEnd(&cmpr_stream);
                   break;
               }

       }while(cmpr_stream.avail_out == 0);

       return uncompressed;
```

}

When the data is hardcoded as in that example, the string is decompressed. However, when I read the response from a HTTP server and store it in a QByteArray, it cannot be uncompressed. I am reading the response as follows and I can see it works when comparing the results on wireshark

```
        //Read that length of encoded data
        char EncodedData[ LengthToRead ];
        memset( EncodedData, 0, LengthToRead );
        recv( socketDesc, EncodedData, LengthToRead, 0 );
        EndOfData = true;

        //EncodedDataBytes = QByteArray((char*)EncodedData);
        EncodedDataBytes = QByteArray::fromRawData(EncodedData, LengthToRead );
```

I assume i am missing some header or byte order when reading the response, but at the moment have no idea what. Any help very welcome!!

EDIT: So I have been looking at this a little more over the weekend and at the moment im trying to test the encode and decode of the given hex string, which is "{status:false}" in plain text. I have tried to use online gzip encoders such as http://www.txtwizard.net/compression but it returns some ascii text that does not match the hex string in the above code. When I use PHPs gzcompress( "{status:false}", 1) function it gives me non-ascii values, that I cannot copy/paste to test since they are ascii. So I am wondering if there is any standard reference for gzip encode/decode? It is definitely not in some special encoding since both firefox and wireshark can decode the packets, but my software cannot.

Comment: Does the HTTP response have a "content-encoding" header field?

Comment: Yup, its 'Content-Encoding: gzip'

Comment: Wait. Does it have a *Transfer-Encoding* header field?

Comment: It does not have a Transfer-Encoding field. Fields are as follows:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Todays date
Content-Length: Length of encoded content

Comment: Are you sure that's gzip data? `inflateInit2(&cmpr_stream, -8)` will use *raw DEFLATE*. gzip-format data should have `windowBits` set to a value between 24 and 31 (set it to 31 or 47 if you don't know what this parameter means, and definitely [spend some time reading up on the zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html)).

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with my gzip function, the correct function I found on this link: [uncompress error when using zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079658/uncompress-error-when-using-zlib)

As mentioned above by Cornstalks the infalteInit2 function needs to take MAX_WBITS+16 as its max bit size, I think that was the issue. If anybody knows any libraries or plugins to handle this please post them here! I am surprised that this had to be coded manually when it is so commonly used by HTTP clients/servers.